# How to do tests AngularJS with Jasmine and Chutzpah?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, chutzpah

I'm new to AngularJS testing with Jasmine. I'm little bit lost with following things.

1. I know Jasmine is used for unit testing. But can someone elaborate that more?
2. And I also want to know how Jasmine and chutzpah work?

I found several tutorials online. But those are little bit hard to understand.
These are the links I followed.

[Testing AngularJS with Jasmine and Karma (Part 1) ― Scotch](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi78K3E4prYAhWJtY8KHYtMBkAQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fscotch.io%2Ftutorials%2Ftesting-angularjs-with-jasmine-and-karma-part-1&usg=AOvVaw0ypXx4DwGvCn-ZfN2z1-CJ)

[AngularJS unit testing tutorial with karma-jasmine](https://ciphertrick.com/2015/08/03/angularjs-unit-testing-tutorial-karma-jasmine/)

If someone can direct me to good tutorials, that'll be great. 
Thank You.

Comment: Asking for tutorials is off-topic. You can start with official guide, https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing . If you're not comfortable with tools, don't pick the one that doesn't have much attention (which Chutzpah is). Pick the default one (Karma).

Comment: @estus I'll look into the Karma. Thank you!